# azure synapse partition table - no performance improvement

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

one of synapse table we've 300 million rows and keep increasing.  Every row as status column i.e active_row either 0 or 1. Active_row is int datatype. Users only   query based active_row = 1 which has only 28 million row and rest of data i.e 270 million is inactive.
To increase the performance and avoid to full tablescan on active_row,   i've converted the table in partition table on active_row as below

```
CREATE TABLE [repo].[STXXXXX]
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED INDEX (
        [ID] ASC
    ),
     PARTITION
    (
        active_Row RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES  (0,1)
        )
)
as
select * from repo.nonptxx;
```

Users reported there is no performance improvement after moving to partition table. when i checked the below query i.e partition vs non-partition i don't see any difference in query explain plain interms of estimated sub tree, operation etc and all stats remain same figure. From sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats  i can see 3 partition created  on partition 1  having 270 million data spilt in 60 nodes and partition 2 of 60 nodes 30 million spilted and partition 3 of 60 nodes is empty.

```
select * from  [repo].[STXXXXX] where active_row =1
```

vs

```
select * from repo.nonptxx where active_row =1
```

Please advise what's wrong and why there is no improvement after moving into partition table and how to tune it?

Answer (score 1):

Are statistics updated?

Run UPDATE STATISTICS [schema_name].[table_name] and rerun your tests (OR create Stats if they don't exist).

You should see a Filter step w/ the smaller number of rows returned when querying a single partition in the tsql query plan right after the Get step. You won't see it in the dsql query plan. You won't see any subtree cost for a Select * which translates to a single Return operation from the individual nodes, however you will see the estimated number of rows per execution get smaller as you filter by partition (w/ stats up to date). Missing or outdated stats can produce some odd query plan results because the optimizer essentially doesn't have enough information to make a good decision...therefore unpredictable and sometimes poor results.

Another option you may want to consider if it doesn't give you the performance you're looking for is keeping the data w/o partitions and simply creating a non-clustered index on the column. Indexes don't always get used or behave exactly how you'd expect w/ SQL server, however in this use case typically a one column index will greatly help performance. The benefit with the index is if you have data moving from active to inactive it doesn't need to move records between physical partitions.